# Create Multidimensional JSON from PHP INNER JOIN table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am a just new learner. I have 3 tables in my mySQL database, 1st "user", 2nd product_detail, and 3rd product_images. and they are join using foreign key. like :
[mySql Tables](http://www.ujagarsingh.com/img/table-structure.jpg), and i am using php PDO oops for desire output.
i want to show a list for specific user's products with product images.
so i am getting object like:

```
[
   {
      "user_id": "1",
      "product_id": "7",
      "product_name": "product title",
      "product_description": "product description",
      "product_img_id": "1",
      "product_img_path": "/products/product1.jpg",
      "product_img_type": "main"
   },
   { ...  },
   { ...  },
   { ...  },
]
```

My Php object Class Function code:

```php
function read(){
   $query = "SELECT
               p.user_id, p.product_id, p.product_name, p.product_description, 
           p1.product_img_id, p1.product_img_path, p1.product_img_type
    FROM        user AS p
    LEFT JOIN   product_description AS p1  
    ON       p.product_id = p1.product_id
    ORDER BY    p.user_id DESC, p.product_id DESC";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt;
}
```

and this is my create object code :

```php
if ($num > 0) {
   $products_arr = array();
   while ($row = $stmt -> fetch(PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      extract($row);
      $product_item = array(
         "user_id" => $user_id,
         "product_id" => $product_id,
         "product_name" => $product_name,
         "product_description" => $product_description,
         "product_img_id" => $product_img_id,
         "product_img_path" => $product_img_path,
         "product_img_type" => $product_img_type
      );
      $products_arr[] = $product_item;
   }
   echo json_encode($products_arr);
}
```

so my need is an object like :

```
{
   "user_id" : "1",
      "product" : [
         {
            "user_id": "1",
            "product_id": "1",
            "product_name": "product title ",
            "product_description": "this is product description",
            "product_images": [
               {
                  "product_img_id": "1",
                  "product_img_path": "/products/product1.jpg",
                  "product_img_type": "main"
               },
               {...},
               {...},
               {...},
               {...}
            ]
         },
         {...},
         {...},
         {...}
      ]
}
```

i want

```
{ **user**
   { all **product** of this user {
        all **images** of this product
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your php code, you would change the following code to the code at the bottom

```
$product_item = array(
     "user_id" => $user_id,
     "product_id" => $product_id,
     "product_name" => $product_name,
     "product_description" => $product_description,
     "product_img_id" => $product_img_id,
     "product_img_path" => $product_img_path,
     "product_img_type" => $product_img_type
  );
```

to the following:

```
$product_image = array(
   "product_img_id"   => $product_img_id,
   "product_img_path" => $product_img_path,
   "product_img_type" => $product_img_type
);

$product = [
    "product_id" => $product_id,
    "product_name" => $product_name,
    "product_description" => $product_description,
    "product_images" => $product_image
];

$product_item = array(
    "user_id" => $user_id,
    "product" => $product
);
```

Comment: no,  after that, there are show user_id with every product_image, and i want every product with all image array. I think in this work use foreach loop.

Comment: you mean you want json to be like 
{ 
    user:[ "user_id":"1","product":[ ] 
    ],
    user:[ "user_id":"1","product":[ ] 
    ]
}

Comment: i want like this : {user :
    [{productName: '',
    productDiscription: '',
    mainImage:
      { 'imageurl': ''},{ 'imageurl': ''},
    ]
 }]
}